# RDF | If something is a rdfs:subClassOf of :Q can you infer it is also rdf:type :Q?

Tags: database-theory, type-inference

Given:

```
:P rdfs:subClassOf :Q
```

Can you infer the following?:

```
:P rdf:type :Q
```

I do not think you can, but I am not fully sure. Whatever the answer is, could you briefly explain why?

*(I am not sure if I should be asking this question here as there are no `rdf` or `rdfs` tags, but it is to do with my CompSci course :})*

Comment: ":P rdf:type :Q" means that the instance ":P" is classified into class ":Q". For example, "Socrates rdf:type :Person" means that Socrates is an instance of Person. In contrast, ":P rdfs:subClassOf :Q" means that every instance of class ":P" is also classified as instance of class":Q". For example, "Person rdfs:subClassOf Mortal" means that every instance of person in the world is also an instance of mortal. Said that, do you think that, from "Person rdfs:subClassOf Mortal" you can deduce that "Person rdf:type Mortal"? I.e., can you say that "Person" is an instance of Mortal?

Comment: When it is written like that it makes a whole lot more sense. It is what I thought, but I couldn't explain why, I guess. I did not fully understand the difference, or what either properly meant - but I do now. Thanks a lot, Juggler :) And no, it doesn't make sense to say ":Person rdf:type :Mortal".